# Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect Prevents Language Selection of CookieRequestCultureProvider

Tags: authentication, cookies, openid-connect, globalization

Using the MS OpenIdConnect middleware locks the culture cookie (CookieRequestCultureProvider) when localizing the application. The app switches languages without the authentication middleware, but stops when reintroduced.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

**Configuration:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    //...
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
    //...
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = OpenIdConfig.SigninUrl;
        options.Cookie.Name = string.Format(".{0}.Cookies", OpenIdConfig.AppName);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(OpenIdConfig.CookiesTimeOut);
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(OpenIdConfig.CookiesTimeOut);

        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            options.Cookie.Domain = OpenIdConfig.SharedDomain;
        }
        options.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager()
        {
            ChunkSize = 4090
        };
        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnValidatePrincipal = async x => await Task.CompletedTask
        };
    }).AddOpenIdConnect(...)
}
```

Here is the Langage select action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
    );

    return await Task.FromResult(LocalRedirect(returnUrl));
}
```

I've tried several culture cookie and auth cookie configurations, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using HTTP or HTTPS? Also does it work if you set options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax; ?

Comment: @ToreNestenius HTTPS and configuring with Lax does work. Thanks Tore!

Comment: Great! Hope you can approve my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use HTTP and also set the SameSite policy to lax:

```
options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core.](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Thanks again, but I made another mistake. I set all of them to Lax. When the cookie expired, I was no longer able to authenticate. I had to change the Auth cookie back to None and leave the site policy as Lax.

Comment: There are many cookies involved, and different cookies need none and some is ok with just lax.